# Porting rqt_rviz to ROS2

Tags: ros2, rqt, ros-humble

I want to use 'rqt_rviz' rqt plugin in ROS2

*https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_rviz*

The source code is ROS1 code, so I tried to change it to ROS2 code.

The modified code build was successful and appeared on the plug-in list in rqt.

When I clicked rqt_rviz, the following message is output and rqt is terminated.

I'd like to ask you guys for advice.

Thanks.

```
[INFO] [1693989215.335931995] [rqt_vlstatus]: Initialized RQT node
[INFO] [1693989215.824198494] [rqt_vlcontrol]: Publisher: logging_json
[rviz_common:debug] Load pixmap at package://rviz_common/images/splash_overlay.png, at /home/voc/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_common/src/rviz_common/load_resource.cpp:71
[rviz_rendering:debug] Available Renderers(1): OpenGL Rendering Subsystem, at /home/voc/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering/src/rviz_rendering/render_system.cpp:301
[rviz_rendering:info] Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED, at /home/voc/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering/src/rviz_rendering/render_system.cpp:543
[rviz_rendering:info] OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6), at /home/voc/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering/src/rviz_rendering/render_system.cpp:284
[rviz_common:debug] Load pixmap at package://rviz_common/icons/plus.png, at /home/voc/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_common/src/rviz_common/load_resource.cpp:71
[rviz_common:debug] Load pixmap at package://rviz_common/icons/minus.png, at /home/voc/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_common/src/rviz_common/load_resource.cpp:71
libGL error: failed to create drawable
libGL error: failed to create drawable
[rviz_rendering:info] Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED, at /home/voc/ros2_humble/src/ros2/rviz/rviz_rendering/src/rviz_rendering/render_system.cpp:543
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This looks more like a libGL error than something strictly concerned with Rviz. Maybe you can look for which particular line causes this `failed to create drawable` error, this can lead to better diagnosis. Also, I'd be happy to learn when you have succeeded in porting rqt_rviz. :)